# Encrypt HTML form (in a jsp) before submit in a .js

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, post

I have got 2 files:

- **send.jsp**: a .JSP with java functions, HTML and a a main in java with javascript functions.
- **identify.js**: a .JS with other (javascript) functions

In send.jsp there is a form (HTML) with some parameters. From this file a function called **save** (identify.js) is called. This function manipulates the form parameters and submits.

Now the question...I would like to encrypt the form parameters just before submitting, that is, inside the function **save**. I have been looking for a method to encrypt parameters in javascript, I tried a lot of code and it simply doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with a method that works in JS? Here the funcion **save**

Thanks!

```
function save()
{var formu=document.identifica;

formu.numContrato.value=l_aux.substr(0,9);
formu.numUsuario.value=l_aux.substr(9,9);
formu.GL_numUsuario.value=formu.numUsuario.value;

/* HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ENCRYPT formu */

formu.submit();
return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using HTTPS?

Comment: I don't know, @Quentin My task is to encrypt these parameters that are sent in POST, I can't change the current structure of files or other but a small intervention in the code. The problem is that using POST, the parameters are visible and someone could exchange POST for a GET, or attack with cross-scripting.

Comment: Define "someone". Do you mean the user typing the data in or a third party attacker?

Comment: a third party attacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

> The problem is that using POST, the parameters are visible and [a third party attacker] could exchange POST for a GET, or attack with cross-scripting.

Your proposed solution (using JavaScript to encrypt what the user types in) is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

You should use the industry standard solution for this problem, which is HTTPS.

This needs to be configured on your HTTP server, it can't be implemented at the client-side code level.

> or attack with cross-scripting

[XSS is an entirely different problem](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) which you need to address in any code which takes user input and outputs it to HTML.